# How to check if there are multiple &nbsp;

Tags: php, regex, string

Is there a way of checking using `if ()` statement if there are multiple `&nbsp;` in a string?
For example this is checking for one `&nbsp;`

```
if ($value == "&nbsp;")
```

`$value` is from `foreach` loop, so I need somehow using RegEx (I guess) check if there are `&nbsp;` (there could be lots of them).

Comment: In other words you want to check if a string contains at least 2 `&nbsp;`?

Comment: The code you gave doesn't check if `$value` contains `&nbsp;` it checks that `$value` is the same as `&nbsp;`.

Comment: If there are only '&nbsp;' and it doesn't matter how many there are of them

Comment: You can split given string by "&nbsp;" and can check count >= 1 as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`substr_count`](http://php.net/substr_count):

```
if (substr_count($value, '&nbsp;') > 1)  {
    ....
}
```

---

**UPDATE** : Response to OP's comment (How to check if in this string are ONLY   without any other character?? ). Alternative that use `str_replace`.

```
if ($value != '' && str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $value) == '') {
    ...
}
```

Comment: But! How to check if in this string are ONLY &nbsp; without any other character??

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis, See punund's answer.

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis, I updated the answer with the alternative that use `str_replace`. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

As you asked for regexp:

```
if (preg_match('/^(&nbsp;){2,}$/', $value)) { ... }
```

This will match if and only if the string is composed of two or more `&nbsp;`s.

Comment: and if string contains 1+ &nbsp; I need to change 2 to 1 of course, yes?

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis, You can change `{2,}` to `{1,}` or `+`.

Comment: in this case it's simpler: `/^(&nbsp;)+$/`

Comment: It should, I tested it.  Check your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (!empty($value));  ?>
```

or You can use substr_count:

```
if (substr_count($value, '&nbsp;') > 1)  {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (substr_count($value, '&nbsp;') > 1)  {    
    $new_str = str_replace("&nbsp;", '', $value); //if you want to replace
}
```